# How to manage django model relations properly?

Tags: django, django-models, orm

Here I am making some tour package system.A  package will have gallery.And of course gallery will have multiple images so I decided to use `ManyToOne` relation here.But I also thought of using `OneToOne` relation between these two models because we can upload multiple images at once through django forms.

So what relation would be best here ?

```
 class TourPackage(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        package_start_date = models.DateTimeField()
        price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        facilities = models.TextField()


    class PackageGallery(models.Model):
        package = models.ForeignKey(TourPackage,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        images = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are correct in creating a `ManyToOne` relation, because you'll probably want to be able to add multiple images to one `TourPackage`.

A few notes:

- `PackageImage`, or `PackageGalleryItem` would be a better name than gallery (One instance is a single image, and not a gallery).
- `images` should be changed to `image`.
- If you add a related_name to `package`, you'll be able to query a `TourPacakage`'s images through that name, like `package.images`.
- Make sure your indentation is correct, because right now, `class PackageGallery(models.Model):` is indented incorrectly, but this could be a copy past issue.

Wrapping it all up:

```
class TourPackage(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        package_start_date = models.DateTimeField()
        price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        facilities = models.TextField()


class PackageImage(models.Model):
    package = models.ForeignKey(TourPackage,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery')
```

Answer (score 1):

> I also thought of using OneToOne relation between these two models because we can upload multiple images at once through django forms.

This doesn't change anything to the relationship's cardinality. An `ImageField` only stores data about one single image file (as it should), writing your views and forms/formsets to allow for multiple uploads only means you'll be creating multiple `PackageGallery` at once. There's nothing magic here...

Oh and yes: I wholefully agree with Nico Griffioen's comments about naming (both for the model and the field).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **Many-to-one** relationship. Because each package can have multiple images. **One-to-one** relationship is only suit if you package have one image.

For more details visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/